# GitHub Actions uploading and downloading artifacts

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github Actions workflow which has two jobs:

1. Compile code to a .exe file and upload as artifact
2. Job that runs on Windows/Mac which downloads the .exe file and uses it.
   However, all of my pipelines have failed, either because a job was for some reason canceled or because there was an error. For reference, here is my latest pipeline run: https://github.com/dantheking-crypto/MakeALanguage/actions/runs/332305074

I would appreciate it if someone could point out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your pipeline above and it seems your `run-on-windows-and-mac` job is missing [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action step. This is why `spark.exe` execution fails. It cannot find `test.spark` file used as an argument (it is in the repo but was not checked out to the runner executing the run). Just add the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) step before executing `spark.exe spark.test` and you should be fine.